# Why do I lose label positions in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I like to work with the label toolbar in qgis, because it is intuitive and I can place labels manually.

However, I lose the position and rotation of labels very often in my cartography workflow. That means I have to repeat the whol process of positioning labels again.

What could be the reason behind that? And how can I prevent it in my future qgis map design workflows?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you move labels manually their positions are stored in an **auxiliary file** coming along with your project (this file has a .qgd extension)

If you  delete this file *(or move its location i suppose...)* QGIS won't find the information.

*In your layers panel right-click on the layer, choose Properties and then `Auxiliary Storage` : You should see how this whole information is stored.*

If you click on these two red icon (for x and y position - those highlighted in your screen capture) you should find a reference to the attributes found in this auxilliary file.

> The **Auxiliary Storage** tab gives some additionnal functionnalities
> like exporting this information enabling you to use these stored label
> coordinates in an **another** project ...

That should be the main reason you lose your labels ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I indeed deleted the *.qgd file. I there any option to save the labeling positions in the project file (qgs / qgz) ? Or an easy way to save the label positions and rotation in the attribut table?

Comment: @EnzoBaldini Just save the values to an attribute.You may be able to reuse the file also I would gues, though I have never tried.

Comment: @EnzoBaldini : If your project file is a **.qgz** your .qgd file should be in the .qgz file. That's the main aim of the .qgz format - keeping those auxiliary information close to the project.
You can check the content of the .qgz by opening it with a common .zip file manager.